# 404 при переносе Yii2 сайта с apache на ngnix

Tags: php, apache, yii2, nginx

На локальном apache все ссылки работали нормально.
При переносе на сервер работает только главная страница index. Переход по ссылкам типа `site/contacts` выдаёт ошибку `404 NOT FOUND ngnix`

Доступа к настройкам ngnix'a нету.

Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: сменой сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Если доступа нет, то сменой сервера.
Если есть, то вот конфиг

```
server {
charset utf-8;
client_max_body_size 128M;

listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
#listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

server_name mysite.local;
root        /path/to/basic/web;
index       index.php;

access_log  /path/to/basic/log/access.log;
error_log   /path/to/basic/log/error.log;

location / {
    # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
#location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
#    try_files $uri =404;
#}
#error_page 404 /404.html;

# deny accessing php files for the /assets directory
location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~* /\. {
    deny all;
}
}
```